# $rootScope.$on($stateChangeStart) redirect to login page if base url hits

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am using angular **ui-router** , **angular-cookies** for authentication in my  ionic mobile application. 
Here is my states

```
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'LogInCtrl'
      })
      .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
      })

      .state('app.search', {
        url: '/search',
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
          }
        }
      })

      .state('app.browse', {
        url: '/browse',
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/browse.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.playlists', {
        url: '/playlists',
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
            controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

      .state('app.single', {
        url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
            controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
          }
        }
      });
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
  });
```

Here is my runs method code

```
$rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
    if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
      $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
    }

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      // redirect to login page if not logged in
        var shouldLogin = typeof $rootScope.globals.currentUser == 'undefined';

        // NOT authenticated - wants any private stuff
        if(shouldLogin || fromState.name === "") {
            var token = $rootScope.globals.currentUser == undefined ? null : $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
            if (token == null) {
                if(toState.name === 'login')
                    return;
                $state.go('login');
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                if(toState.name === toState.name)
                    return;
                //TODO: Check token
                $state.go(toState.name);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
```

Authentication work fine but when I changed my url to **http://localhost:8100/** it redirects to login page , however it show go to playlist page . Need help what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think you do not have any state mapping for the url pattern "/" that is why it will go to other wise which is "/login" as per your app js so it is showing login page.

Comment: What is `typeof $rootScope.globals.currentUser` when said redirection is happening?

Comment: Also, it is suggested that you use the `resolve` function in the state definition for authentication instead of polluting your `$rootScope` with global functions. You can instead create an authentication service and inject it into whatever state you want to authenticate. And also use some global configuration within your `.config` function to inject any headers you'd want

Comment: Its is false @nikjohn

Comment: Why it is redirecting to login page when I hit only base url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is being redirected to the base url because:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

There's no state defined for `/`, so the router hits the `otherwise` condition and redirects to `/login`